# Delete multiple rows from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete multiple rows from mysql database using php code this my code but i have this message error how to solve this ?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'on' at line 1

```
$files_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_files where db_isdeleted='1'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
          if(mysqli_num_rows($files_query)>0){
          echo"<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'><tr>";
          echo"<td style='background:#f7ac01;font-size:16px;text-align: center;'><input type='checkbox' class='allcb' data-child='chk'/></td>
               <td style='background:#f7ac01;font-size:16px;text-align: center;'>FileName</td>
               <td style='background:#f7ac01;font-size:16px;text-align: center;'>Date</td>";
        echo"</tr>";      
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($files_query)){
              $id=$row['db_id'];
              $name=$row['name'];
              $date=$row['db_date'];
              echo"<tr>";
         echo'<form method="post" action="">';
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='txt_table' value='tbl_files'>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='txt_action' value='files'>";    
         echo"<td style='text-align: center;'><input type='checkbox' name='item[]'  class='chk'/></td>";        

         echo"<td style='text-align: center;'>$name</td>";

         echo"<td style='text-align: center;'>$date</td>";

          }
      echo"</tr>";
      echo"</table>";
            echo"<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger'>&nbsp;";
            echo"<input type='submit' name='restore' value='Restore' class='btn btn-success'>";
             echo"</form>";
      }
```

/************************

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
      $table=$_POST['txt_table'];
      $action=$_POST['txt_action'];
       foreach($_REQUEST['item'] as $id) {
        // delete the item with the id $id
    $delete_query=mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE db_id=$id")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    header("location:recyclebin.php?action=$action&msg=1");       
    }
  }  
?>
```

Comment: can you echo your query here?

Comment: In your code there isn't the work 'on' .. be sure that this code is the right one

Comment: This is not good, you have an sql injection problem and you are opening your form in the loop but closing it outside of the loop (and the table...). On a place where you cannot even use a form or form fields...

Comment: DELETE FROM tbl_files WHERE db_id IN (8) @Jigar7521

Comment: ok thanks, but now here scais seems right

Comment: @Jigar7521 what is this error and  no delete

Comment: i think the problem is in query of white space or something while it will executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for my english.  :)
your code has many "problems" :), but...

Three steps to make it works:

First, **form** must be created before *while* cycle:

```
echo'<form method="post" action="">';    
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($files_query)){
```

Next, you must provide IDs of db rows (add **value="$id"** to checkboxes):

```
echo"<td style='text-align: center;'><input type='checkbox' name='item[]'  value="$id" class='chk'/></td>";
```

and in *form "action"* php file,  you are redirecting after FIRST iteration. Move redirect AFTER foreach cycle:

```
  foreach($_REQUEST['item'] as $id) {
        // delete the item with the id $id
    $delete_query=mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE db_id=$id")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    }
header("location:recyclebin.php?action=$action&msg=1");
```

But your code is really bad and unsafe, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Bad, because its "confused" code without any standards. Unsafe - not only sqli. aslo header injection, xss, csrf, ...

Comment: Can you please give some tutorial to learn how to solve this error ?!!